# How do you tell the difference between speakers and microphones?

Tags: speakers, microphone

How do you tell the difference between speakers and microphones?

I pulled the following two components out of an old cell phone
and cannot tell them apart.

[image: microphone and speaker]

Each have two metal contacts on the back.

Comment: Are you sure they're not both speakers?  One for external and one for the ear?

Comment: I thought about that but the component with the three holes in the center was located underneath the hole at the mouth piece end of the phone.
I'm starting a Circuits and Devices class here soon so I'm going to hook the 'microphone' up to a function generator and then an oscillator to see what happens. The speaker I've already hooked up to a function generator.

Comment: If you pulled a component out of the mouthpiece, doesn't that mean it's a microphone?

Comment: True but it was awhile ago and I couldn't remember which came from which end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The speaker is the yellow device on the right-hand side, the microphone is the device on the left, with blue plastic/metal visible.

The speaker will almost inevitably be larger then the microphone. Also, you can actually see the [voice-coil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_coil) in the speaker - it is the copper colored oval.

@markrages - is somewhat correct about measuring impedance, but not correct about the internals. The speaker should read as a fairly low impedance - less than 100 ohms.

However, in all likelyhood, the microphone is a [Electret Microphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electret_microphone), which uses a capacitor which varies in capacitance in response to air pressure waves, e.g. sound.

Getting a meaningful signal out of an electret microphone is pretty simple, but they do not produce an output without being *biased* with a power supply. Basically, they need a little bit of power to run, and you have to supply them with that.
Fortunately, there are lots of schematics freely available, and they're generally pretty simple.

Comment: An electret doesn't need bias. See your citation.

Answer (score 2):

You can measure the impedance.  Speakers generally have lower impedance than microphones.  Otherwise they are really the same thing, a transformer between sound and electrical energy.

Comment: `Otherwise they are really the same thing` - This hasn't been true in anything but some (musical) instrument microphones for decades. Everything on the market at this point pretty much uses little electret mics, which are a whole different ball-o-wax.

Comment: The little speaker in my older PC is a piezo disk with a high impedance, 250ohms at 2khz, no continuity with dc.